# Find the real and imaginary parts of z

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How can I start to solve this kind of equation ? Kind of stuck on getting the right answer too.

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2}{2+j3}+\frac{1}{3-j2}$$

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac 1z=\frac{2(2-3j)}{2^2+3^2}+ \frac{3+2j}{3^2+2^2}$$
$$\frac 1z=\frac{7-4j}{13}$$
$$z=13*\frac{7+4j}{7^2+4^2}$$
$$z=\frac 75+ \frac{4j}5$$

Comment: Just to ask how did u get 2^2 + 3^2 from 2(2-3j)/(2^2+3^2)? Anyway the answer is what I am looking for :D

Comment: @QingYong $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$ in other words: $(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2 - (ib)^2=a^2+b^2$ (I've multiplied the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{3-j2} = \frac{j}{j(3-j2)} = \frac{j}{j3+2}  = \frac{j}{2+j3},$$
so:
$$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{2+j}{2+j3}\quad\to\quad z=\frac{2+j3}{2+j}.$$
Now, multiply by $\dfrac{2-j}{2-j}$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2}{2+j3}+\frac{1}{3-j2}$$
$$=\frac{2(2-j3)}{2^2+3^2}+\frac{3+j2}{3^2+2^2}$$
$$=\frac{2(2-j3)}{13}+\frac{3+j2}{13}$$
$$=\frac{7-j4)}{13}$$

$$z=\frac{13}{7-j4}$$ $$z=\frac{13(7+j4)}{7^2+4^2}$$
$$=\frac{13(7+j4)}{65}$$
$$=\frac{7+j4}{5}$$ $$=\frac{7}{5}+j\frac{4}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a}{b}=ab^{-1}$$

So 
$$ z^{-1}=\frac{2}{13}(2-j3)+\frac{3+j2}{13}$$
$$z^{-1}=\frac{7-j4}{13}$$
$$z=\frac{1}{5}(7+j4)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorm:**

$\forall a,b,c\in{\Bbb{R}}$,

$$\frac{c}{a+bi}=\frac{c}{a+bi}\cdot\frac{a-bi}{a-bi}=\frac{c(a-bi)}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{ac}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{bc}{a^2+b^2}i$$

**Situation:**

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z}&=\frac{2}{2+3j}+\frac{1}{3-2j}\\&
=\frac{4-6j}{13}+\frac{3+2j}{13}\\&=\frac{7-4j}{13}
\end{align}

Taking reciprocal of both side,

\begin{align}
z&=\frac{13}{7-4j}\\&=\frac{91+52j}{65}\\&=\frac 75+\frac 4 5j
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2}{2+3i}+\frac{1}{3-2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2(2-3i)}{(2+3i)(2-3i)}+\frac{1(3+2i)}{(3-2i)(3+2i)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{4-6i}{2^2+3^2}+\frac{3+2i}{3^2+2^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{4-6i}{13}+\frac{3+2i}{13}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{4-6i+3+2i}{13}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{7-4i}{13}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{13}{7-4i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{13(7+4i)}{(7-4i)(7+4i)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{91+52i}{7^2+4^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{91+52i}{65}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{91}{65}+\frac{52}{65}i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{7}{5}+\frac{4}{5}i$$